# How to set default environment in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

How can I set the default environment in Spring Boot?

I put in `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.include=prod,dev
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

and in user variables:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = dev
```

So when I dev in my comp my environment are dev but when I generate my `.war` and deploy in tomcat he still using `dev` with enviroment (I deploy in another comp with no other conf)

How can I set my default environment (if he don't find any in user variables or commmand line uses production)?

Answer (score 6):

What you need is:

1) Define the active profile you need, something like:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

In this example the loaded file will be `application-dev.properties`

Now, if you need to switch to a different environment depending where are you installing your war file what you can do is to set this variable as a system variable in each environment you want, that way each environment has a different value for the same key, something like:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

In my case I am using Tomcat and I declare this key/value in the file `setenv.sh`, you need to assign that value depending on the server you're using.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Spring Boot guide on profile specific properties

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

I would remove what you have from your application.properties. You are telling it to include (not replace) both dev and prod profiles. A much easier setup is to have

1. application.properties (if no profile is set)
2. application-dev.properties (for dev  profile)
3. application-prod.properties (for prod profile)

Comment: jst I dont understand  today I put the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev in my windows system variables, but when I run bootRun the Spring get my config from application-prod.properties i remove that 2 lines from my application.properties but spring still get from prod.

Comment: Are you sure it is coming from application-prod and not application.properites? Also are you sure the windows variable is being set correctly? You should be able to print out the value of that variable to confirm it's value.

Comment: in my application.properties I only have this: server.contextPath=/portalservicosback
spring.main.show_banner=false
spring.jackson.date-format=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
spring.jackson.mapper.USE_ANNOTATIONS = true
logging.file=portalservicosback.log

Comment: this is my system variables prints..
:findMainClass
:bootRun
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=LumeraEbner
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\fabioebner\AppData\Local
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
Platform=MCD
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0=C:\java\sencha\cmd/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.3.61
USERDOMAIN=LumeraEbner
LOGONSERVER=\\LUMERAEBNER
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
SESSIONNAME=Console
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
...

Comment: Sorry this is my environment variables. now I does this:    public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "development");    
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    } and dont work too

Comment: And you named the file application-development.properties and put those in src/main/resources? Can you post the three properties file in your question (just the important parts, not every key value pair). And then show the code that prints out what is not set correctly.

Comment: I already try with dev and development  i will put one by comment

Comment: application.properties
server.contextPath=/portalservicosback
spring.main.show_banner=false
spring.jackson.date-format=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
spring.jackson.mapper.USE_ANNOTATIONS = true
logging.file=portalservicosback.log

Comment: application-dev.properties
elastic_ip=7natal.lumera.com.br
elastic_porta=9300
elastic_size=30
#BANCO
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portalservicos
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

Comment: and application-prod.properties
elastic_ip=123.123.23.2
elastic_porta=9300
elastic_size=30
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/ConectorPortalServicos

Comment: all files are in src/main/resources/

Comment: Don't add all that code to the comments section of an answer. Edit your question and add it to that part so other users can help you solve your problem.