# How to load the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE value in the client service dynamically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am new to spring and creating a spring cloud config service. I have successfully created the configuration service where all the configurations are there. In my client service(this will fetch all the necessary configurations from the configuration service) I need to fetch the configurations depending on the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` value which is defined in the manifest file. There are multiple manifest files in the client service and each has its own `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` value. 
Currently I am using `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="profile_name")` i.e manually defining the "profile_name". But, I want to make it dynamically i.e depending on the value of `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` the value should be fetched from configuration service.
Can anyone please suggest me how to load the value dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use `-Dspring.profiles.active={your-profile}` as application start up argument rather than specifying in configuration file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865442/how-to-set-default-environment-in-spring-boot

Comment: I can use it but I want to pick it from configuration file

Answer (score 10):

Pass `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` as environment variable to Spring Boot app instead of declaring it in yaml and hard coding it in configuration file. The app picks the corresponding yaml based on the profile.

[How to pass spring profile as parameter to spring boot app](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#4-jvm-system-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

> depending on the value of SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE the value should be fetched from configuration service.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get configuration from a Config Server based on the active profiles in the client app. Spring Cloud Config Client does this automatically, [as described in the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#_locating_remote_configuration_resources). For example, if the client app has `spring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2`, then at boostrapping the config client will make requests to the Config Server with URLs like

```
https://my-config-server.example.com/sample-app/profile1/master
https://my-config-server.example.com/sample-app/profile2/master
```

and load the response from each request into a property source in the client app.

Comment: Using that I am able to load my configuration file. But, currently facing problem to read it in my client service. Working on that. Can you pls suggest something?

Comment: Applications typically don't load and read configuration files from a config server directly. The config client automatically loads them into the Spring Environment, where the values from configuration can be read like local configuration (e.g. as described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config). Is there a reason you need to load the files directly?

Comment: I want to fetch the configurations from the file